# c# Using setting dynamic expression dynamically?

Tags: c#, dynamic

I'm new to the dynamic keyword and been researching it quite a bit, for I want to use it to parse xml.  I came across this example I'm using as my test: http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/kevin-hazzard/fluent-xml-parsing-using-cs-dynamic-type-part-1

In the example, they show: `dx.book[2].authors.author[0].name.last.Value`, I want to know if it's possible somehow to build a dynamic expression from a string or database value?

psuedo example:

```
dynamic dx = new DynamicXml(xml);
Console.WriteLine("dx.book[2].authors.author[0].name.last.Value");
```

I looked into an EVAL to do something like this, or looking into reflection somehow, but curious if there is a better way.  Any advice or help, or a simple no would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to execute code in string-form? In other words, a code-as-data approach like the Javascript eval() method?

Comment: @Sean Thoman: not exactly.  I have my dynamic object created (compiled, and executed at runtime), I just want to be able to use different dynamic expressions on my dynamic object at runtime.  I would find this very helpful for xml, so I can have any xml schema, and be able to parse it with the same code.  Ultimately if this is feasible, I would then pass the parsed xml values onto another class for further processing.  If that makes sense at all or not, my terminology on this concept is fuzzy.

Comment: I think something like XPath would be more appropriate for what you are trying to accomplish. It's a query language for XML, where you have an XPath expression string which can be used to select nodes in an arbitrary XML structure.

Comment: @Stefan, I agree, overall I was just trying new things and wanted to use this dynamic keyword for the experience, but I am familiar with xpath and have used it before, so I may just go that direction again.  I may keep this open though just to see if anyone else has ideas as well.  Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

[InvokeGetChain](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/source/browse/ImpromptuInterface/src/Impromptu.cs#569) takes a string of properties and dynamically invokes them. It is more of a reflection style way of doing it (though easier and faster than reflection and works with dynamic objects.

It's in the ImpromptuInterface open source project (via nuget). As of v6.0 it does parse indexers, in the exact format above, excluding the target object.